# Letters in IBAN: How to calculate the hash

Tags: bank-account, european-union

Until I got an account in France, I didn't know that you can have letters in your account number. Since it's in EU, I've got IBAN with the account, which shows the letter as well, and it has a two-digit hash code so it looks like this:

```
FR55 2004 1000 0123 4565 4Y32 177
```

The original account number is in the format:

```
ETABL 24001,   GUICHET 00001,   No COMPTE 12345654Y321,   CLE RIB 77
```

How is `Y` considered when the IBAN hash is calculated? (Remark: I made up the above number so `55` is probably not the correct hash.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the [calculation of the check digits](http://www.europebanks.info/ibanguide.htm#5), any alphabetical characters are replaced by 2-digit numbers consisting of 9 plus the position of the character in the Latin alphabet, so

```
 A -> 10 
 B -> 11 
 etc.
```